# unable to connect reliance netconnect+ ZTE AC2738 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I am unable to connect my reliance netconnect+ (ZTE AC2738) in ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have tried all the methods and options given to me but am unable to connect my usb modem. my provider said they support only till 10.04..

Comment: did you install install modem drivers on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Install wvdail and gnome-ppp in ubuntu 12.04
Run $sudo gnome-ppp

Then pop-up appears,
In the pop-up enter

- Login: net
- Password: net
- phoneno: #777

Hit connect and wait for couple of minutes. It will get connected.

If it doesn't connect, restart your machine and try again.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I could connect.... No issues.

Just follow the complete guideline on http://practicalubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/11/relience-netconnect-usb-modem-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.